# RN - native module callbacks in multiple call

Tags: android, callback, react-native

I developed a native android module to send SMS from React Native app.

The scenario:

1. In RN app I have a list of customers with 'Send SMS' button for each.
2. Clicking the button calls the native module's send method. **The broadcastReceiver calls a callback** upon successful sending.
3. RN receives the callback's returned success status.

Now when I click the button and wait for the callback to proceed everything works fine. *However* when I **quickly** press 3 'send SMS' buttons for different customers, SMSes do get sent (so on Android module side it's ok - 3 calls queue up and launch one after another untill all are done) **but** only the last callback's returned value arrives at RN app. The app must get 'feedback' from native module for all SMSes to customers, not only the last one.

My understanding is that it's due to the fact that native modules (as docs say) have a callback firing only once - so it looks like the last one just replaces the previous ones..?

However I would expect callbacks's returned value to stack/queue up and arrive at RN consecutively after each call to native module completes. I call the native module 3 times and so they are **3 separate calls** (I don't expect 3 callbacks from one call to native module).

Any hint? I may have spent too much time on this and so overlooked some obvious stuff..

Comment: In my experience there's no problem with multiple call / multiple response. Can you share your native function and javascript call?

Comment: Val do you make these multiple calls one after another, I mean next AFTER the previous returns reponse? Because what I mean is making multiple calls fast ie. BEFORE the initial ones  manage to complete. They should then bring their responses later in a queue - that's what I would expect. Like in raw Android Studio I make a button that shows a Toast - you press it 10x in a row, each with different msg and then they show up one after another. In RN only the last toast would show up. ps. Sure, I can edit my qs and post code when I come back home.